# Jest tests failing for Reactjs rating field material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to write a jest test for the rating ui field in material ui.

In the past it was working with something like this

```
 it('rendering and submitting a basic Formik form', async () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn()

    const { container  } = render(<GeneralFormik schema={schema2} submitHandler={handleSubmit} />)
    const user = userEvent.setup()

    await act(async () => {
      
      await user.click(screen.getByLabelText(/4 Stars/i));

      expect(screen.getByLabelText(/4 Stars/i)).toBeChecked();

    });
    
    

    await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /submit/i}))

    await waitFor(() =>
        expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            rating_field: 4
        }),
    )    

  })
```

[image]

it complains now that toBeChecked is the wrong approach that its not a radio field -- I've tried something with fireEvent - but its as if it doesn't change/select the field.

```
await act(async () => {
  const radio = screen.getByLabelText(/4 Stars/i)
  await fireEvent.change(radio, { target: { value: 4 } });
  expect(radio.value).toBe('4')
})
```

what is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following solution

```
  it('rendering and submitting a basic Formik form', async () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn()

    const { container  } = render(<GeneralFormik schema={schema2} submitHandler={handleSubmit} />)
    const user = userEvent.setup()

    await act(async () => {
     await fireEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText(/4 Stars/i));
    });

    expect(screen.getByLabelText(/4 Stars/i).value).toBe('4')

    await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /submit/i}))

    await waitFor(() =>
        expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            rating_field: 4
        }),
    )
  })
```